# Convert absolute path to clientrelative path

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

Using ASP.NET how can I convert a absolute path to a relative client path?

Eg.: Today I have a address like that: 'c:\web\site\images\somefile.some' I want to convert to "/site/images/somefile.some", It is worth to say that "site", "images" and somefile.some may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Question will help you: [Absolute path back to web-relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)

That said, why are you using an absolute path rather than the ~/ which is suggested?

For example, if you use "~/images/somefile.some"  and pass it to the [Control].ResolveUrl(url as string) method, then it would translate that into the path for somefile.some based on the root of the directory.

Comment: I get this URL from an app.config, there is an application that salves the images files in webserve.