# Get files in a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file

In my MVC application I have the following paths;

- /content/images/full
- /content/images/thumbs

How would I, in my c# controller, get a list of all the files within my thumbs folder?

**Edit**

Is Server.MapPath still the best way?

I have this now `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/content/images/thumbs") );` but feel it's not the right way.

is there a best practice in MVC for this or is the above still correct?

Comment: The above (`Server.MapPath`) is correct and acceptable in my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Directory.GetFiles("/content/images/thumbs")
```

That will get all the files in a directory into a string array.

Comment: @Daniel i can't get this to work.  it maps at c:\content\images\thumbs rather than at my web application level.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you're trying to do? It sounds like you're trying to return a list of file paths to the view. In that case, in the view, try using `<%= Server.MapPath(filePath) %>`, where filePath is a local path.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that `Server.MapPath()` actually converts a server path to a file path. Looking for some other solutions now...

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path

Seems a bit brittle though. I'd probably just get the filename using `Path.GetFileName(file)` and append the virtual path in front of it.

Answer (score 52):

.NET 4.0 has got a more efficient method for this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/thumbs"));
```

You get an `IEnumerable<string>` on which you can iterate on the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
<ul>
    @foreach (var fullPath in Model)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        <li>@fileName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: If you have problem with finding _Server_, check out this question : [Cannot use Server.MapPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105768/cannot-use-server-mappath)

Comment: Can you serve these files by providing a link to the full path, or do you need a handler for that?

Comment: @selectDistinct Not sure what you mean. Server.MapPath converts the virtual path into a physical directory path. Of course the process that executes the code needs the right to access this path. The OP asked for a list of files