# Attach metadata to image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, metadata

Assuming my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039910/get-files-in-a-folder) gets answered what are the options to attaching meta data to an image in my thumbs folder?

I thought of placing an xml file in the folder which contains the filename and then the description of it but feel this to be a little clunky.

For various reasons I can't use a database in this project which is very limiting.

Is there a way to write meta data to the jpg file?

The problem i'm trying to solve is that I need to display the image along with a short description of what it is.  kinda like a caption if you like.

Any thoughts would be very welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an application that writes metadata into the image file itself into the various namespaces IPTC, EXIF, IFD and XMP. The code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/muruge/meta-public). You can use the code to write/read metadata to and from the images. Hope this helps.