# Cannot use Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, server.mappath

What I must do to make `Server.MapPath` work?
I have `using System.Web;`

what else? When I type `Server` there is no quick result option (intelli-sense) for `Server`.

Any help?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What kind of project is this? Why are you wanting to run Server.MapPath? Is this a web-forms project and are you writing code in a Page subclass or in an ASPX's render function?

Comment: C# Winforms.. i want it to check for file availability on the server

Answer (score 313, accepted):

you can try using this

```
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
```

or use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`

```
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
```

Comment: They not working.... Error 1 The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ... Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: it looks like your are using winforms, you might wanna see this link then http://www.debugging.com/bug/18951

Comment: Me too, __HostingEnvironment.MapPath__ worked and I am using it outside of a controller.

Comment: First of all your project needs to reference System.Web.dll and it will work

Comment: How to get read a file present in this directory "~/AppData/Roaming"?

Comment: For my case, `HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/MyFolder")` returns c:\inetpub\wwwroot\. Need to add `HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyFolder")` to return the **correct** path.

Answer (score 19):

Your project needs to reference assembly `System.Web.dll`. Server is an object of type `HttpServerUtility`. Example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
```

Comment: Cant't find such reference I found only this two: System.Web.ApplicationServices, System.Web.Services....

Answer (score 8):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")` gives null if we call it from a thread.

So, Try to use

`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/")`

Answer (score 3):

Firt add a reference to `System.web`, if you don't have. Do that in the **References** folder.

You can then use `Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles/"));
if (!IsExist)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles/"));

StreamWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles/") + "FileName.csv"));
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
csvWriter.WriteRecords(classVM);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `System.Web` as a reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference (`System.Web`) 
[Reference to System.Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCfKQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few years old, but what I do is add this line to the top of your class and you will still be able to user Server.MapPath

```
Dim Server = HttpContext.Current.Server
```

or u can make a function

```
Public Function MapPath(sPath as String)
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sPath)
End Function
```

I am all about making things easier. I have also added it to my Utilities class just in case i run into  this again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I guess this might help someone. As the Original Poster of this question asked

> What I must do to make Server.MapPath work?
> I have using System.Web;

The class which we had written should implement **System.Web.UI.Page**

Say for example, our classname is **MyClass**

```
public class MyClass: System.Web.UI.Page
{
// Code runs here 
}
```