# Accessing txt file which is in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read some text from file

```
public void loadFromFile(string adress)
    {
        //int preventReadingEntireFile = 0;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(adress))
            {
                //preventReadingEntireFile++;
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(preventReadingEntireFile + ": " + line);

                /*
                 * TODO: dodawanie słów do bazy
                 */
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to access this file (what the path is). I placed it in one of folers in my solution in my project. When I use "/TxtFiles/odm.txt" it searches for this file in "C:\TxtFiles\odm.txt" (which is wrong, there aren't any files like that there).

Is it possible? Do I have to make this file somehow "visible" for my scripts?

This is ASP.net mvc 5 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`Server.MapPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for it, which will generate absolute path of the file from relative url, the below code will work if **TxtFiles** directory is in root directory of Application:

```
StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/TxtFiles/odm.txt"));
```

for you case:

```
string adress = "~/TxtFiles/odm.txt";
StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(adress));
```

Comment: which "using" should I use? VisualStudio proposed me "Microsoft.SqlServer.Server" but simultaneously says that there isn't anything like "MapPath" in this class

Comment: @Ludwik11 you are using it in controller or in some class?

Comment: It is under ``System.Web`` nanespace

Comment: In class. I already have System.Web namespace declared, but VisualStudio still says that "The name 'Server' does not exsist in the current context"

Comment: ``System.Web.HttpContext.Current. Server``

Comment: Check this as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105768/cannot-use-server-mappath

Comment: Thank you :) I have one more question, not exactly connected with subject of discussion: where in VisualStudio can I see text written by "Console.WriteLine" function?

Comment: On **Output** window I guess

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Windows? A lot of programming languages (or rather, their file-handling libraries) interpret a starting slash '/' Unix-style, as "begin at the root of the file system", in your case, C:. Try doing "./TxtFiles/odm.txt", with an initial dot - this is conventionally interpreted as "start at the current directory".

Another option is to just use the full path, "C:\MyProjects\CurrentProject\TxtFiles\odm.txt".