# How to use an external Json File to serve as a data source for webapi

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Following is my code snippet which works fine, my query follows the code:

***Model:***

```
namespace CVHub.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Context
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int sessionID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static List <Context> Contexts= new List<Context>
        {

            new Context{sessionID=1,Name="Name1"},
            new Context {sessionID=2,Name="Name2"},
            new Context {sessionID=3,Name="Name3"}
        };
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
namespace CVHub.Controllers
{
    public class ContextController : ApiController
    {
        List<Context> items;
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Context> Get()
        {
            //return Context.Contexts;
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

Question: I want to use an external json file (residing in app_data folder) to serve same data instead of doing `new Context{sessionID=1,Name="Name1"},` 
how to use a data I read from json file? I am very new to MVC and webApi, so it will be of great help if the experts can post the entire working code or as much details as possible please.

Comment: So you don't know how to read the file? Or you don't know how to fill your model properties based on the json that you read?

Comment: I dont know how to fill the model properties with the data read from external json file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return a `HttpResponseMessage` with your JSON file loaded into  `StringContent`.

```
public class JsonFileController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/contexts.json");

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }
}
```

**App_Data/contexts.json**

```
[
    {
        "sessionId": 1,
        "name": "name1"
    },
    {
        "sessionId": 2,
        "name": "name2"
    },
    {
        "sessionId": 3,
        "name": "name3"
    }
]
```

Comment: interesting, I will give it a shot. Please let me know what will the model look like in this case.

Comment: It will return your .json file, so what ever is in your .json file will be returned. So that should contain valid json

Comment: `Server.MapPath` may not work for some users please see the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11105933/3997521

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the answer, I am fairly new to .Net/C#, now I wanted to consume the same ApiController for load the local JSON file, how can I pass the ApiController  in AJAX URL, would it be /api/JsonFileController?

function loadColorPalette() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/JsonFileController',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success", data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error("error", err);
        }
    });

I believe, it's not the right URL, isn't it?