# Why server.mapPath is Invalid report file path in production but local machine is valid?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i spend a lot of time to resolve this problem but to working. I use server.mapPath function to specific valid path file. why only local machine is working but not working in production because i this (server.mapPath) is a great function

**c#**

```
[WebMethod]
public string getDocument(string id, string location)
{
  ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
  report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/report1.rpt"));
  Stream stream = report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
  MemoryStream streamReader = new MemoryStream();

  stream.CopyTo(streamReader);

  return Convert.ToBase64String(streamReader.ToArray());
}
```

**ajax**

```
function printPreview(reqID) {                        
            var base_url = "/Webservice/webService.asmx/getDocument";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url,
                data: "{'id': " + reqID + ", 'location':'" + objUser.location + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.d)
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
```

**Check API backend**
Look like the problem happen when ReportDocument.Load because i test in production with File.Exists function without ReportDocument.Load and the result return file is exist but cannot load why ? Have any one else know this ?

**error exception**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

I'm add bindingRedirect from 13.0.2000.0 -> 13.0.3500.0 in web.config and still not working. I'm see in server production C:/Windows/assembly all of (CrystalDecisions.Shared, CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, CrystalDecisions.ReportSource) is version 13.0.2000.0 but why another project is working. Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: use .. at the place of ~

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Server.MapPath("../Reports/report1.rpt")

Comment: same error, working with local machine but not in production

Comment: How about this System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);

Comment: Just try to find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105768/cannot-use-server-mappath

Comment: @Shubham, I'm already try HostingEnvironment.MapPath, because i working with asp.net web api and i get the same error that i post so i try to create .asmx file to user Server.mapPath and the result return the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try without the tilde and forward slash character.

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/report1.rpt"));
```

This expects report (.rpt file) to be available in 'Reports' subfolder of your application root folder

Comment: i use ~/ for start with the root of path folder then go to Reports folder because my service.asmx file is inside another folder.

Comment: Crystal report tries to create a temporary file in **C:\Windows\temp** folder before reading or writing files. Make sure the permission is there. I would also suggest changing the identity of the application pool to currently logged in user. Basically, you have to do a trial and error method to resolve this.

Comment: other project that i make in the same server not have a problem. I'm use log4net to log error and i add all assembly that show in error but still error (Invalid report file path) but it go through if file.Exists(same path). it make me confused.

Comment: Loading a crystal report in a web application is not straight forward as loading a file, it does various tricks under the hood. Can you try using an absolute path to the report file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *System.IO* `Path.Combine`. There you just add your Foldernames and your Filename and get a correctly formatted Path. Could look something like that:

```
string sPath = Path.Combine(@"\\" + "Reports", "report1.rpt");
```

You can add string variables (Foldernames) with just a comma.

Comment: Please see more information that i'm edit. i test file exist with out crystalDocument.load and it return true (that file is exist)