# Why the file stream is reading wrong path?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, filestream

I am trying to access textfile present in the folder inside the solution.

```
Dim fs As New FileStream("../CMMS/Webservices_URL.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

but it always picks c drive even though the solution is somewhere else. why it's happening?

`Folder1/Folder2/CMMS/Webservices_URL.txt` is the actual path but it picks `c:/CMMS.`

Comment: Remove the '../'

Comment: You probably want the [HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8), and if it isn't happy about it then see [Cannot use Server.MapPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11105768/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the physical path of a file in Web Forms you need to call `Server.MapPath("~/Folder1/Folder2/CMMS/Webservices_URL.txt")`

you can find the details here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8