# I am using Razor mvc and i would like to show images and files after a actionlink clicks from a folder called"UploadedFiles"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

When I click the ActionLink It's redirecting to the controller followed by folder name and file name like this:

http://localhost:50078/Profile?DisplayFile=%2FUploadedFiles%2F11AAAAA1111Z1A820182809163738-Screens.docx&target=_blank

Below is the code:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Click to View", "",  new  { list.DisplayFile, target = "_blank" })</td>
```

Comment: What exactly you want? Are you trying to show image or file in MVC view? For example, lets assume that there is a file named **testfile.pdf** and **testimage.jpg** In your **UploadedFiles**. Now what you want? Are you trying to open image or pdf in your browser (as your referral link understanding) or you want to see both file and image altogether? @Niranjan

Comment: i want to see both file and image @ZiaulKabirFahad

Comment: [stackoverflow link for get all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352435/6311571) with this you can get all file path within a folder so you could show images or file(file name/file as a dummy image) in your view. @Niranjan