# Absolute path with disk name (C:\\) to relative path (~/)

Tags: asp.net, url, path

Any built in way to get virtual / relative path or URL from absolute path containing disk name such as?

Or how to convert this :

C:\\ProjectRoot\\Somedir\\demo.text

to this

~/Somedir/demo.text

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET absolute path back to web-relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Request.PhysicalApplicationPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx) will give you the physical root of your virtual directory.

So in your case if your virtual directory was at c:\projectroot, then you'd want ~/somedir/demo.txt right?

So if you did a string replace on the file path, replacing Request.PhysicalApplicationPath into a tilde character, along with swapping \ for / , then you'd get what you needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i did in the same way, seems that this is the only way.