# Convert windows path to web path in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, relative-path, absolute-path

I used `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/abc.jpg")` to get the Windows Path for a file in my web application.

Now I want the reverse. From the windows path that I got, I want to get the web path that I had earlier passed as parameter to Server.MapPath. How to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081433/getting-relative-virtual-path-from-physical-path

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute path back to web-relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowsPath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);`

Found this at:
[Absolute path back to web-relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)