# How to convert physical path to virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below you can see the path that has been stored in the database and what i need it to look like. So I can use the path to change an image.

From the Database:

> C:\Users\AlphaDog\Desktop\Alumni Revised\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\image\Vince\Tulips.jpg

Needs to be changed to:

```
~/image/Vince/Tulips.jpg
```

Comment: Not clear, what does the first path means? Is it where your Website is hosted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting relative virtual path from physical path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081433/getting-relative-virtual-path-from-physical-path)

Comment: The first path is the root path where I saved it from the database. Then I need to get the path from Database to change the image but it cannot be change.

Comment: @gunr2171 not a duplicate man

Comment: @User072912 Convince me it's not and I'll remove my close vote

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a virtual directory that points to image folder.

Comment: @User072912 please walk me trough your issue. You ran a query over a table in a database and it brought back one row with one field with the result being your first string. What do you want to do with it? Where that path is pointing to? Your WebApp or some other folder?

Comment: @SanjaySahani I want to use the saved path in my database to change the image in my website form. But using the path that comes from my database it cannot be replaced.

Comment: @Dalorzo That path pointing to the path where my WebApp project located. The "Vince" there is the user's image folder..

Comment: @User072912 this is not clear. Sorry you are explaining your issue correctly.

Comment: @Dalorzo I uploaded an image in my WebApp project. Also, I have an image folder in my WebApp. Then in my project I will upload an image then the root path of the uploaded image is saved in the database which is showed above.. I want to use that path to my Image in WebApp project like eg.. Image1.ImageUrl = "~/~/image/Vince/Tulips.jpg"

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have enough repetitions of AlumniTrackingSystem in your path. I think another 2 should do the trick.

Comment: @BenRobinson, you forgot a closing </sarcasm> tag in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick.  A little more code than the previous answer, but you know, sometimes I like to do things the hard way.

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\AlphaDog\Desktop\Alumni Revised\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\image\Vince\Tulips.jpg";
    string[] splitPath = path.Split('\\');
    int start = 0;
    foreach (string s in splitPath) {
         if (s == "image")
             break;
         else
             start++;
    }
    string virtualPath = "~/";
    for (int i = start; start < splitPath.Length; start++) {
         virtualPath += (i > start ? "/" : "") + splitPath[start];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you are looking for:

```
String RelativePath = AbsolutePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
```

it should work if your app phisical path is:

```
C:\Users\AlphaDog\Desktop\Alumni Revised\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\AlumiTrackingSystem\
```