# Convert Image path stored in sql db to understandable for <img src=""/> tag in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, image, src

I have one mvc application. In that when I am submiting the form, storing the image at server and that image path storing in sql db.But now i want to give that path to `<img />` tag but in my database path is stored like this,

> E:\From Rahul\OnlineFilling\OnlineFilling\FileManager\Consumer\101_we_cccce_ProfPic.jpeg

and image tag require src in this format like,

```
<img  src="~/FileManager/Consumer/101_we_cccce_ProfPic.jpeg" />
```

so how can i convert this path in C#  that is in controller...?

Comment: Try searching. Create an action method that accepts an ID, looks up the row with that ID, looks up the path and returns the file contents of the image present at that path. Then your link becomes `/Controller/Image/42`.

Comment: better to save the desired path directly to db or make the changes in your controller

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8411683/205988

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What MVC you user? Most of the MVC have this function $base_url() or similar, so it returns your app root address, either the "E:\From Rahul\OnlineFilling\OnlineFilling" from local or an address like "www.example.com/myApp" form a real server. Searching the documentation of and MVC can do you no harm. Hope it gives you an idea.