# get relative path from root folder for a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem to create a correct download link for a file.

This is the expected and working result (correct path): http://localhost:60000/ManualMeterDocuments/client/Exports/client_0985-20160318-211554.xlsx

But this is what MVC makes of it:
http://localhost:60000/ManualMeters/~/ManualMeterDocuments/client/Exports/client_0985-20160318-211554.xlsx

ManualMeters/ => the controller.

In my controller action at a point I get the physical path:
C:\Data\Test\source\Portal\Portal\ManualMeterDocuments\Client\Exports\Client_0985-20160318-214256.xlsx
and try to return the relative path.

I've tried different things but can't get it right.

```
var virtualFilePath = exportFile.Replace(Server.MapPath("~"), "~/");
return Json(virtualFilePath, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is the value in the var virtualFilePath returned from the controller to jquery ajax call. From there I bind it to a `<a>` href tag:
 ManualMeterDocuments\Client\Exports\client_0985-20160318-215243.xlsx

So that path is ok, but somehow somewhere ManualMeters/ is added to the link.

EDIT: this is what I should be able to put in the href attribute to get the download working:
            test

Comment: what is the value coming in ``exportFile``?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting relative virtual path from physical path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081433/getting-relative-virtual-path-from-physical-path)

Comment: This is the value in exportFile: C:\Data\Test\source\Portal\Portal\ManualMeterDocuments\Client\Exports\Client_0985-20160318-214256.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it: ..\

```
 var virtualFilePath = Path.Combine(@"..\" + exportFile.Replace(Server.MapPath("~"), ""));
```

Returns:

```
http://localhost:60000/ManualMeterDocuments/Client_0985/Exports/client_0985-20160318-224049.xlsx
```

And why the bs to close this question?