# How to get server path of physical path ? 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, path, relative-path, virtual-path

I want to convert this physical path `"C:\bla\bla\Content\Upload\image.jpg"` to server path like `"/Content/Upload/image.jpg"`.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Where? In the client-side or server-side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET absolute path back to web-relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use something like that :

```
 public static class Extensions        {
        public static string RelativePath(this HttpServerUtility utility, string path, HttpRequest context)
        {
            return path.Replace(context.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], "/").Replace(@"\", "/");
        }
    }
```

and you call

```
Server.RelativePath(path, Request);
```

Comment: Isn't this the reverse of what the OP asked?

Comment: Oh sorry, I rewrite the response

Comment: thanks, its good solution but i prefer to use HttpServerUtilityBase instead of HttpServerUtility abnd HttpRequestBase instead of HttpRequestBase. working well also.

Comment: +1 even if I think it's not a good idea to add an extension to a class where at least one property or method are used in the helper method. In this case, the RelativePath could be at a better place in a helper class like PathResolver. What do you think?

Comment: @Samuel Yes, it's just a quick sample but actually you could create a helper class that fits your needs called like you said a PathResolver.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to get the relative path.

```
String filePath = @"C:\bla\bla\Content\Upload\image.jpg";

String serverPath = Request.PhysicalPath;
String relativePath = filePath.Substring(serverPath.Length, filePath.Length - serverPath.Length);
```