# MVC 3 image upload path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image, path

I m trying to upload an image and a thumbnail.

I have set the upload path in web.config as `<add key="UploadPath" value="/Images"/>`

when i upload the image, it get the full path of the hard drive and folder that application is in|:

```
D:\Projects\Social\FooApp\FooApp.BackOffice\Images\image_n.jpg
```

But i just want `/images/image_n.jpg`

I m using `Path.Combine` do u think that the reason?

how can i resolve this?

this is the code|:\

```
foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        if (fileName != null) originalFile = Server.MapPath(upload_path) + DateTime.Now.Ticks + "_ " + fileName;


                        file.SaveAs(originalFile); 

                        images.Add(originalFile);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get server path of physical path ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436460/how-to-get-server-path-of-physical-path)

Comment: How are you getting the full path of the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx).

> *Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.*

Your code can look something like this:

```
Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);
```

*EDIT - I'm adding to the code you've provided above. It would look something like this.

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var uploadPath = "~/Images"; //This is where you would grab from the Web.Config. Make sure to add the ~

        if (fileName != null) {
            var originalFile = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath), DateTime.Now.Ticks + "_ " + fileName);
            file.SaveAs(originalFile); 
            images.Add(originalFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Path.Combine works on virtual path also?  I always used it for physical file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code is in one of your controllers. 
Have you tried:

```
Server.MapPath(yourPath);
```