# Displaying image on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

How to display an Image if I have the `Physical Path` of that image in webpage in a particular place?

I tried like below but not working.

```
            img = rdr["ImagePath"].ToString();
            img = Server.MapPath(img);
             Image1.ImageUrl=img;
```

Comment: `Physical Path` where? on server or on client's machine?

Comment: You may find this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path

Comment: This won't work, 'coz the path is on the server not on User's machine.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it would be as below:

```
ImageInstanceName.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(@"/Images/image.jpg");
```

Or if you were wanting to do it in markup then @Bibhu's solution should work.

Here is the link to MSDN library on [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Handler which returns the binary output of that image. and in your image tag refer to this handler

eg. `<img src="yourImagehandler.ashx"/>`

Answer (score 2):

In C# -

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("c:\path\to\file.jpg");
```

Comment: -1 "The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path **to** the corresponding physical directory on the server" - your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying like this `Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(img);` But it's not showing the image.

Comment: See the link I posted as a comment to your question (this question has been asked before). The above code doesn't work so you shouldn't upvote it.

Comment: Relative path is in most cases the one good for that. hdougie's answer is more suitable

Answer (score 2):

```
  <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Image text"
       ImageAlign="left"
       ImageUrl="images/image1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I need to get the path from sql query can you tell me how to do in that case