# How to split url path in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, url-rewriting, split

I have got image url path like :

```
http://localhost:3810/images/test.png
```

What I am looking is to split the path and just get the path for instance : /images/test.png
using razor.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: are you looking for a [site root relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Uri class like this:

```
@{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:3810/content/images/thumbs/0000019.png");
    string path = uri.PathAndQuery;
}
```

The `path` variable will be `/content/images/thumbs/0000019.png`.