# retrive file path from database to set Image control

Tags: asp.net, database

I used `FileUpload` control and `Server.MapPath` to load an image file `url` to database. Then I want to get this image file `url` from database and set the Image control in `Asp.Net`. How can I do that?

When I load the image file `url` to database is look like this in database:

```
C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\cesme_pano\cesme_pano\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

I set this `url` to `Image.ImageUrl` control, but it didn't work. How can I solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace your \    with    `/`

Comment: Problem not just wiht slash characters. When I give the image path as hard coded also didn't work. Image1.ImageUrl="~/image.jpg" this also didn't work. I use this code in Page_Load method.

Comment: See my answer - `ImageUrl` needs to be a relative to the website path which is my standard file paths won't work.

Comment: Thansks @NickW, Your solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/asp-net-absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path) is what you are looking for. What you are trying to do is convert a physical path to a virtual one that ASP.NET understands.

The suggestion is to go:

```
String RelativePath = AbsolutePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
```