# Image not getting displayed mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am storing the physical path of pictures in a table and I am trying to display the image in a view.

I am fetching it and storing it in a Model and storing it in a string property before sending it to a strongly typed view.

I am trying to display the image using the following code:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(@Model.imageUrl)" alt="Image"/>
```

If I view the source of the page the path is correctly getting loaded as shown below, but the image is not getting displayed.

```
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\dinesh.sekaran\Desktop\My 
  Files\OnlineShoppingSystemMVC\OnlineShoppingSystemMVC\Resources\iphone5s.jpg"
  alt="Image"/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your `@Model.imageUrl` binary data ?

Comment: What does that string contain?

Comment: Location of the picture in my system nothing else

Comment: @RandomUser Are you getting 404 error? Look at the console for errors, something else is wrong.

Comment: I tried to load the relative path as suggested by @Oualid it worked

Comment: No error is shown only alt message is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a relative path instead and put you image in the images folder in your app.
@Model.imageUrl should suffice if it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should not expose directly a physical path of your server to your browser, and that's exactly what you're doing.

You need to convert the physical path to a virtual path.

If the path of the folder where you store the files is inside your site, you can replace part of the physical path with the virtual path, like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path).

If not, you can always make a link to an action that returns a `FileResult` that contains the image. To do so you need to create an action in a controller that receives an identifier, or the path or whatever, that identifies your image, and return the image file in a `FileResult`.

Answer (score 0):

This path cannot be used , because it is a security issue, you have to use project folder relative path for the source adress like :

```
<img src="/Resources/iphone5s.jpg" alt="Image"/>
```

this will solve your problem.