# unable to load a local resource OR virtual path error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**Situation**

I have two applications that both read and save images / documents to one specific folder. Example if the user uploads their image in one program, a user of program B is supposed to view and even edit that image.

**What I have done**

In one of my application I have created a setting in settings for the string of my path. So to save an image path I call

```
 path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.imagePath, Fimage);
```

this works fine.
However, my issue is when I try to view the image in my edit view.

*Controller*

```
 ViewBag.imagePath =   Properties.Settings.Default.imagePath;
```

*View*

```
 <img src="@ViewBag.imagePath/@Url.Content(@Model.image)" alt="Image" style="height: 255px;  " />
```

**Problem**

The problem is upon attempting to view the image I get the error, `Not allowed to load local resource:` I have full access to the folder and when I attempt to browse to the file in the error message the picture is displayed. I was advised from other questions to use, `server.MapPath` however when I do  `Server.MapPath(Properties.Settings.Default.imagePath);` I get the error physical path received, expected virtual path.

This viewbag holds the entire string of folder my files are stored with the *EVERYONE* user having full access. So i'm really unsure of why it's making a fuse.

P.S I cant say something like `"~/content/images"` because the path to that file is in an entirely different application, I think I need to give it the entire location.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Gratitude

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `defaultImage` variable holds a physical path, which will work for saving the image since the API requires a path in the form e.g. `c:\website\images\....` but for viewing, you need the `VirtualPath`, something of the form `http://mycoolsite/images/image.jpg` and this is what the error is telling you.

Your Controller; therefore, should return something like

```
ViewBag.imagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.imagePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
```

In order to get the Relative Path. See this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path).

**EDIT** I just saw your "PS..."

If that's the case, then you need to pass the full URL to the other application: (e.g. `http://someothersite.com/images/image.jpg`).

Comment: Revering to your Edit, how do I state that in my config, im trying    `<value>http://someothersite/Manage/Content/Image/</value>` and im getting is not a valid virtual path.